# group by two fields and sum another for each group

Tags: json, csv, jq

I'm interested doing a jq grouped columns by sum.

I tried with arrays but I could't. I need to add pupils grouped by Level and Genre.

My json is like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Maths",
    "Level": "One",
    "Genre": "Boys",
    "pupils": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "English",
    "Level": "Two",
    "Genre": "Boys",
    "pupils": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "Maths",
    "Level": "One",
    "Genre": "Girls",
    "pupils": 7
  },
  {
    "name": "English",
    "Level": "One",
    "Genre": "Girls",
    "pupils": 6
  },
  {
    "name": "Social",
    "Level": "One",
    "Genre": "Boys",
    "pupils": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "Social",
    "Level": "Two",
    "Genre": "Girls",
    "pupils": 0
  }
]
```

And I need to convert to csv like:

```
One, Boys, 9
One, Girls, 13
Two, Boys, 3
Two, Girls, 0
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I tried several commands. I thought it could be something like: `jq -r 'group_by(.Level, .Genre)[] | [.[0].Level, .Genre, (map(.pupils) | add) | @csv' pupils.json` but no...

Comment: You were close, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very similar to [your previous question](/questions/61953604/group-objects-by-a-field-and-sum-another-then-produce-a-csv-report). You just need to group by `Genre` after `Level`.

```
  group_by(.Level)[]
| group_by(.Genre)[]
| [.[0].Level, .[0].Genre, (map(.pupils) | add)]
| @csv
```

Comment: I've been referencing this answer while working on some stuff and noticed that `group_by` can take a generated expression to sort by, so the two usages of `group_by` can actually be combined!
`group_by([.Level, .Genre])[] | [.[0].Level, .[0].Genre, (map(.pupils) | add)] | @csv`

Comment: @SamuelJackson with newer versions of JQ it should work without square brackets as well https://jqplay.org/s/kKtNB3yc_wD